# How do I backup Microsoft Outlook 2007 files?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

How do I backup Outlook 2007 files?

Can I use these backed up files with Outlook express? Where is the default location for these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File > Data File Management

Put your mail in .PST's.  Copy them to your backup location. Outlook may need to be closed to copy them.

Answer (score 3):

Do note that that Outlook contacts become unusable in Outlook Express

Comment: One way to make them usable in Outlook Express is to import and export into Google contacts in respective formats. May not be the best way, but it works. ;)

Comment: True. but in places where 'net access is restricted/firewalled/websensed this is ruled out. Speaking from personal experience

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Microsoft's free [Personal Folders Backup](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8b081f3a-b7d0-4b16-b8af-5a6322f4fd01&displaylang=en) tool. It runs when Outlook exits, and has simple schedule support ("every N days").

I'd then copy the backup to a USB stick, an online storage account, or some other off-machine storage for safety.

As far as Outlook Express (Windows Mail in Vista) is concerned it does have an import wizard, via File menu, Import, Messages.